# Tkinter GUI Updating Problems (Python)

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am currently having a problem with a GUI in Tkinter. I have concocted an example to illustrate my point:

```
import tkinter as tk
import time

bob = tk.Tk()
bob.geometry("100x70")
bob.resizable(0, 0)
## Initialises the window and makes it look pretty


label = tk.Label(bob, text = "Test")
label.pack()
label.place(x=40,y=25)
## Initalises a label and makes it look pretty as well

def some_task():
    print("Hi")
    label.config(text = "Not a test anymore")
    time.sleep(5)
    print("Bye")
```

If you run this code, you will notice that even though the label is updated before the program waits then prints "Bye", the GUI is updated last. This is a problem for me, because my program requires to show the user some things on the screen as it is happening.

Does anyone know why this is? Is there any way to fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is it full example? Seems like something is missing. For example, you not calling `some_task()` at all here.

Answer (score 0):

In general, to use timers in tkinter, you should be using `bob.after` method. For example, by changing your code as follows:

```
import tkinter as tk
import time

bob = tk.Tk()
bob.geometry("200x70")
bob.resizable(0, 0)
## Initialises the window and makes it look pretty


label = tk.Label(bob, text = "Test")
label.pack()
label.place(x=40,y=25)
## Initalises a label and makes it look pretty as well

def some_task():
    print("Hi")
    label.config(text = "Not a test anymore")
#    time.sleep(5)          # <-- comment out this
    print("Bye")

bob.after(5000, some_task)  # <-- use after to call some_task() after 5s.

bob.mainloop()
```

Will result in the following actions:
1. Tk window with the label containing "text" is shown.
2. 5 seconds passes and the label is updated to "Not a test anymore"